# Robots.txt being read, but not being followed

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, robots.txt

This is the code I have for my crawler, I believe I basically have all the components I need, some may just be out of order, I know that robots.txt is being read. Unfortunately it is still spitting out urls that shouldn't be in visited. Can someone help me?

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.robotparser

url = "http://www.imdb.com"

urls = [url]

visited =[]

robotsUrl = url +'/robots.txt'

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

while len(urls) < 1000:
    parse = urllib.robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    parse.set_url(robotsUrl)
    parse.read()
    if parse.can_fetch('*',urls[0]):
        try:
            htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
        except:
            print (urls[0])

        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
        urls.pop(0)
        print(len(urls))
        for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            link['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,link['href'])
            if url in link['href'] not in visited:
                urls.append(link['href'])
                visited.append(link['href'])
print (visited)
```

Pseudo code:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
     link['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,link['href'])
     #something like if parse.can_fetch('*',link['href']):
          if url in link['href'] not in visited:
               urls.append(link['href'])
               visited.append(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated: Based on comments. Included a set to hold all unique URLs collected**

It's not that the robots parser is failing. It's your `visited` array and when you append to it.

You'll actually want to move the `visited.append(link['href'])` to right after the try/except block, and instead use the URL you just visited as the passed value » `visited.append(urls[0])`.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.robotparser

url = "http://www.imdb.com"

queue = [url]

visited =[]
unique = set([])

robotsUrl = url +'/robots.txt'

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

while len(queue) < 1000:
    parse = urllib.robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    parse.set_url(robotsUrl)
    parse.read()
    if parse.can_fetch('*',queue[0]):
        try:
            htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(queue[0]).read()
        except:
            print (queue[0])

        visited.append(queue[0])

        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
        queue.pop(0)
        print(len(queue))
        for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            link['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,link['href'])
            if link['href'] not in visited:
                queue.append(link['href'])
                unique.add(link['href'])
print("visited: ", visited)
print("uniques: ", unique)
```

That way you'll append only when you've successfully crawled a URL. Additionally, when you do the check to see if you've already crawled the URL, it'll be checking against the appropriate URL set.

I also changed the `if` statement in the `for` loop.  It's using the extracted link to check against visited.

Comment: I see where you are going and it does indeed work. The problem is I want to be able to print off a list of the urls I have in total. It is my fault for not explaining that. But I want to make sure that it only scrapes the urls that I will be able to later follow when put back into the loop.

Comment: @Dakotabartell, I'm not sure I exactly follow. But I'm under the impression that you want a list of all the links (i.e. URLs) that you've collected during the crawl?

If that's the case, you might want to create a 3rd array that contains that information and place it where the `visited` array used to be in the `for` loop.

It's pretty common for crawlers to have an queue that you push and pop from like you have with `urls` but also a data structure to hold the data that you've collected.

Comment: @Dakotabartell I've update the code block above. I'm not sure if this satisfies what you're looking for. You could add logic to the `for` loop's `if` statement to check if the `link['href']` is crawlable, by calling `parse.can_fetch` again, but I think it's overkill. You'll be doing that anyhow  in the `while` loop and you're not incurring that much additional cost because you're not going to hit the `urllib.request` for URLs you can't navigate to.

Comment: I don't know why but more disallowed links are getting through. Basically what I need is something that strips the href links off a page and before it appends the url list, it runs it through a check on the robots.txt to see if it is allowed. I will put in some pseudo code in my original post for some guidance.

Comment: Basically when I print urls, I don't want any links in there that are on the disallow list

Comment: I have figure out this problem.